# Netlify deployed site view different than local jekyll serve

Tags: jekyll, liquid, netlify, jekyll-theme, netlify-cms

I am trying to deploy a jekyll website, specifically, in the [Jekyll Uno](http://joshgerdes.com/jekyll-uno/) template. The local view is completely fine, however, when I tried to deploy it, it looked something like [this](https://soumik.netlify.com/). P.S. the github repo is [this](https://github.com/srdg/jekyll-uno) and the local view looks like [this](https://srdg.github.io/jekyll-uno). Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're moving from gh-pages to Netlify deploy. You then have to change some configuration.

In **_config.yml**, change

```
url: 'https://srdg.github.io'
baseurl: '/jekyll-uno'
```

to

```
url: 'https://soumik.netlify.com'
baseurl: ''
```

You can also stop publishing on gh-pages by going in repository **settings** and set **Github Pages** >> **sources** to `none`. This can avoid you to have duplicate content and SEO problems.

Comment: It did work, thank you for the suggestion. However, it seems the original URL which was supposed to [https://soumik.netlify.com/](https://soumik.netlify.com) is now prepended by some kind of an alphanumeric string, namely [https://5be44ea8ec8a89223eb2b12b--soumik.netlify.com/](https://5be44ea8ec8a89223eb2b12b--soumik.netlify.com/). What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. [https://soumik.netlify.com](https://soumik.netlify.com) is working fine. (I was viewing the deploy preview) Did the prepended string come from the deploy or commit version?

Comment: Each commit as a preview prefixed with commit number.